Computing difference of error functions to high precision
Given $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$, I want to compute $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^y e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t = \mathsf{erf}(y)-\mathsf{erf}(x),$$ where $\mathsf{erf}(z) := \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^z e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t$ is the error function.
Standard numerical libraries include methods to compute the error function. So I could use these methods to compute the integral above.
However, this potentially suffers from catastrophic cancellation when $x$ and $y$ are close. That is, suppose we have a method $\widetilde{\mathsf{erf}}$ that calculates $\mathsf{erf}$ with relative error $\pm\varepsilon$. Then
$$\widetilde{\mathsf{erf}}(y) - \widetilde{\mathsf{erf}}(x) = \mathsf{erf}(y)(1\pm\varepsilon) - \mathsf{erf}(x)(1\pm\varepsilon) = \mathsf{erf}(y)-\mathsf{erf}(x) \pm (|\mathsf{erf}(y)|+|\mathsf{erf}(x)|) \varepsilon.$$
Since $|\mathsf{erf}(y)|+|\mathsf{erf}(x)|$ may be much larger than $|\mathsf{erf}(y)-\mathsf{erf}(x)|$, the relative error may be enormous. I want a good relative error guarantee.
Standard numerical libraries also include the complementary error function $\mathsf{erfc}(z) = 1-\mathsf{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_z^\infty e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t$. This gives better accuracy when both $x$ and $y$ are large, but doesn't help when, say, $x$ and $y$ are near $1/2$.
One solution is to use the Taylor series: $$\mathsf{erf}(y) = \mathsf{erf}(x) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}\left( (y-x) - \frac12x(y-x)^2 + \frac16 (x^2-1) (y-x)^3 + \cdots \right).$$ (The coefficients of the Taylor series are given by the Hermite polynomials.)
This works well when $x$ and $y$ are very close together, but rapidly becomes unwieldly.
Surely this problem has been studied and there must be good general-purpose solutions. Any references would be greatly appreciated. Ideally I would like a read-to-use Python implementation.
Note that I want methods that work for complex $x,y$, but methods for real values would be a good start.

Re "Surely this problem has been studied and there must be good general-purpose solutions." A review of the literature does not support this hypothesis. Generally speaking, accurate computation of the complex error functions itself across the entire domain already appears to be a significant challenge. Fredrik Johansson's arbitrary precision ARB library includes the complex error function, but existing Python bindings for ARB may not cover relevant functions yet.
